# Appcelerator Titanium How do I add google play services api jar to my android module?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-modules

How do I add google play services api jar to my android module?

Hello everyone, I tried following the documentation. What I did is:
Set `build.properties` `google.apis` path to `C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\extras\\google\\google_play_services\\libproject\\google-play-services_lib\\libs`
Then I add the jar from the above path to my Java Path.
Then I copy the jar from the above path to my module's `android/lib` folder. Then I build the module with success (I don't make any API call, just build with the defaul module code it comes when you create a new module using studio).
Then I add the module to my project and execute it.
While it's executing, it takes a long time at Running dexer: line, and after a while it throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

I'm able to run my application with my module if I remove this jar from the module, so it's not other jars or code from the module causing the issue. Please, I've been trying all day and it's driving me insane. Thanks.

Comment: Does this link offer you any help?
http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/11/integrating-an-external-library-in-an-android-module/

You need to mention this in the TiModule.xml otherwise it will not be used for the build purpose.

Comment: @Soumya It was a little more complicated than this, I'll post the full answer for reference after. A very helpful user at slack helped me to solve this.

Comment: That will be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @NotGabriel can you please share the full answer? I'm having the same problem. Thanks.